# How can I plot a function with two variables in Octave or Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I want to use Octave to plot fairly simple functions with two variables like: f(x,y) = x^2 + 3y .  It is very easy to plot single variable functions, but I am having a lot of trouble finding out how to do two variable functions.  Does anyone know the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Plotting a function of two variables would normally mean a 3-dimensional plot - in MATLAB you would use the function plot3 for that. To plot your function f(x,y) in the interval [-10,10] for both X and Y, you could use the following commands:

```
x = [-10:.1:10];
y = [-10:.1:10];
plot3(x, y, x.^2 + 3*y)
grid on
```

Answer (score 9):

In case it may help someone out there... I ran in Octave the code in the accepted answer and I got this plot:

[image]

But I really wanted the function for every point in the Cartesian product of x and y, not just along the diagonal, so I used the function [mesh](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) to get this 3D plot with the projected contour lines in the x,y plane:

```
x = [-10:.1:10];
y = [-10:.1:10];
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
z = xx.^2 + 3*yy;
mesh(x, y, z)
meshc(xx,yy,z) 
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("y");
zlabel ("f(x,y)");
title ("f(x,y) = x^2 + 3y");
grid on
```

[image]

To get rid of the mesh-wire texture of the plot, the function [surf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html?searchHighlight=surf&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) did the trick:

```
x = [-10:.1:10];    
y = [-10:.1:10];
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
z = xx.^2 + 3*yy;
h = surf(xx,yy,z);
colormap hsv;
set(h,'linestyle','none');
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("y");
zlabel ("f(x,y)");
title ("f(x,y) = x^2 + 3y");
```

[image]

Another way to plot is as a [heatmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) with contour lines:

```
x = [-10:.1:10];
y = [-10:.1:10];
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
z = xx.^2 + yy.*3;
contourf(xx,yy,z);
colormap hsv;
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("y");
zlabel ("f(x,y)");
title ("f(x,y) = x^2 + 3y");
grid on
```

[image]

And for completeness, the levels can be labeled:

```
x = [-10:.1:10];
y = [-10:.1:10];
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
z = xx.^2 + 3*yy;
[C,h] = contour(xx,yy,z);
clabel(C,h)
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("y");
zlabel ("f(x,y)");
title ("f(x,y) = x^2 + 3y");
grid on
```

[image]

Comment: This is a superior answer. The visuals help beginners searching for assistance best with things like this.  Showing multiple options provides highest value.

Comment: All you need now is `surfc` [(see documentation)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surfc.html) to make this answer canonical.  I hope you add.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent answers from [@Toni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249912/8239061) and [@esskov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868179/8239061), for future plotters of functions with two variables, the [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) and [`contourf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) functions are useful for some applications.

[image: Contour & Filled Contour Plots]

MATLAB Code (2018b):

```
x = [-10:.1:10];    
y = [-20:.1:20];
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
z = xx.^2 + 3*yy;           % Borrowed 4 lines from @Toni

figure
s(1) = subplot(1,2,1), hold on  % Left Plot
    [M,c] = contour(xx,yy,z);   % Contour Plot
    c.ShowText = 'on';          % Label Contours
    c.LineWidth = 1.2;          % Contour Line Width
    xlabel('X')
    ylabel('Y')
    box on
s(2) = subplot(1,2,2), hold on  % Right Plot
    [M2,c2] = contourf(xx,yy,z);
    colorbar                    % Add Colorbar
    xlabel('X')
    ylabel('Y')
    box on
title(s(1),'Contour Plot')
title(s(2),'Filled Contour Plot')
```

---

Update:  Added example of [`surfc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surfc.html)

[image: 3D Surface with contours below]

```
h = surfc(xx,yy,z)
```

Comment: I didn't realize you had added the contour plot when I edited my answer with a flat contour plot.

Comment: @Toni No worries. Your answer was masterful and I just thought this should be added too. I see you added `contourf` at same time as my post. Your answer is now just about canonical...