# Surface Plot of Multivariate Normal Density

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have a likelihood function with [Multivariate Normal Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) whose mean is `mu=[3 5]'` and `covariance=9*I`. How can I plot its 2D surface in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

The log-likelihood function can be obtained from the PDF or by referencing the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Properties).

```
Mu = [3 5]';
Sigma = 9*eye(2);
loglikeh=@(x) -0.5*log(det(Sigma)) + (x-Mu)'*inv(Sigma)*(x-Mu) + length(x)*log(2*pi);  % For single x

xMin = -2;
xMax = 7;
step = 0.1;
X1 = xMin:step:xMax;
X2 = xMin:step:xMax;
L = zeros(length(X1),length(X2));
for i = 1:length(X1)
    for j = 1:length(X2)
       x = [X1(i) X2(j)]';
       L(i,j) = loglikeh(x);
    end
end
```

**Plotting**

```
surf(X1,X2,L')      % Note L is transposed if done this way
xlabel('x_1')
ylabel('x_2')
zlabel('log-likelihood')
```

[image: log-likelihood surface plot]

---

<sub>See [How can I plot a function with two variables in Octave or Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061) for more visualizations and options.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You may try to refer in here:
(use mvnpdf function in MATLAB) 
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma)
Please check here https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html

Comment: The multivariate Normal probability density function (PDF) and likelihood function are not the same thing.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Properties)