# Plotting a piece-wise surface plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, surface, piecewise

I'm trying to learn how to plot a surface plot with piece-wise conditions but cannot figure it out on my own. This is what I have thus far:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10,0:.1:4);
Z =  ((X.^2)/100).*(1-(((Y-2).^2)/4));
C = X.*Y;
surf(X,Y,Z,C)
colorbar
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
%The block of code above looks great for what I need initially

% Now the commented code below is what I was working on and 
% I feel that I have defined the piece-wise function correctly 
% but cannot plot it properly

% syms p(Y)
% p(Y) = piecewise(Y<2, 1, Y>2, -1)
% [X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10,0:.1:4);
% Z = zeros(size(X));
% Z = p(Y).*(((X.^2)/100).*(1-(((Y-2).^2)/4)));
% C = X.*Y;
% surf(X,Y,Z,C)
% colorbar
```

The second block is somewhat based on how this could be done in maple. However based on MATLAB documentation, this seems to be the most correct version after having attempted slight variations.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a simple [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). In general, it is best to ensure these are vectorized (use `.*` rather than `*`, `.^` instead of `^`) to maximize their utility and integration with other MATLAB functions.

```
yh =@(y) 1*(y<2) + (-1)*(y>2);  % note yh(2) = 0 (can change this if reqd)

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10,0:.1:4);
Z = yh(Y).*(((X.^2)/100).*(1-(((Y-2).^2)/4)));
C = X.*Y;
surf(X,Y,Z,C)
colorbar
```

[image: Surface plot]

*Disclaimer:* I acknowledge my lack of skill with MATLAB's symbolic capabilities. I'm sure another user can provide an answer if that's required.

**Other visualizations:** Future visitors may be interested in other plot types for 3 variables (e.g. X,Y,Z). Good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help this does do what is needed however I will still be interested in knowing how to do this with the piecewise function if possible.

Comment: Me too. I have zero experience working with MATLAB's symbolic toolbox. I do 100% of symbolic work in Wolfram's Mathematica.