# How to plot a surface over a constrained domain?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, surface

How would I plot the surface:

`z=(1+x^2)/(1+y^2)` over the region `|x|+|y|<=2` ?

I cannot get the surface constrained to the rhombus/square-shaped region.

Comment: What have you done that isn't working?

Comment: Related but not a dupe (lacks the constraint): [How can I plot a function with two variables in octave or matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example:

```matlab
% Create a grid in X and Y:
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(-2:0.01:2);

% Evaluate Z according to the equation:
ZZ = (1+XX.^2) ./ (1+YY.^2);

% Introduce constraints using NaN
XX( abs(XX) + abs(YY) > 2 ) = NaN;

% Plot:
figure(); surf(XX,YY,ZZ, 'EdgeColor','interp');
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `NaN` trick does not respect the true boundaries of the domain (in the proposed answer the resulting roughness of boundary is hidden by the fine sampling). It would be better the generate the parametric surface itself, like this (I deliberately used a large step to highlight isoparametric curves)

```matlab
% create a grid in the parameters domain
[U,V] = meshgrid(-1:0.2:1);

% compute actual (X,Y) values in the domain
X = U-V;
Y = U+V;

% Evaluate Z according to the equation:
Z = (1+X.^2) ./ (1+Y.^2);

% Plot:
figure(); surf(X,Y,Z, 'EdgeColor','interp');
```

[image]