# How to make a surface plot of a 3 dimensional array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a three-dimensional array where the three dimensions have different sizes - (the x is 4, y = 40, z = 50). Could you'll help me out on how to make a surface or 3D plot of it in MATLAB?

Comment: a 3D matrix where each location has a single value is not plottable with surface. You have volume data, and you need to plot volume information. Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab/27660039#27660039

Comment: Is Z a function of X & Y?  If so, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061

Comment: Z is function of x and y, but not a linear one. Z is the power output of a rover, x is the number of motors and y is the angle of the incline it's on.