# 3D Graph of the Function f(x,y)=xsin(xy)exp(-(x+y)/10)

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D plot of f(x,y)=xsin(xy)exp(-(x+y)/10) uisng the `surf` command. My code is below:

```
x=linspace(-5,5,400);
y=linspace(-3,3,400);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=x.*sin(x.*y).*exp(-(x+y)/10);
surf(X,Y,Z);
shading interp;
```

The error `Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector` is being displayed. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You probably want `Z=X.*sin(X.*Y).*exp(-(X+Y)/10);`. With your current code you generate `Z` as a vector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot a function with two variables in octave or matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868074/how-can-i-plot-a-function-with-two-variables-in-octave-or-matlab)