# Plot a surface in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I want to plot a surface in MATLAB using surf. I have this equation: `x = y^2 +4z^2`.

What I am doing is the following:

```matlab
[x,y] = meshgrid(-4:.1:4, -4:.1:4);

z = sqrt((x - y.^2)./4);              % Basically I'm just clearing for z

surf(x,y,z)
```

But with this I am getting the error: `Error using surf X,Y,Z and C cannot be complex`. I know there is a complex number because of the values that `x` and `y` have, plus the square root. Is there another way to plot a surface in MATLAB? because I really don't know what to do, and my skills are very basics.

Comment: If you're just interested in the real part of `z`, you can write `z = real(sqrt(...))`. The following `surf` command then will execute without problems.

Comment: Very closely related: [How can I plot a function with two variables in Octave or Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel that you need to grid `x` and `y`, and not use the form of the original equation itself?

This seems to work perfectly fine

```
[y,z] = meshgrid(-4:.1:4, -4:.1:4);
x = y.^2 + 4*z.^2;
surf(x,y,z)
```

to produce

[image]