# Create surface plot in MATLAB using x,y,z array

Tags: matlab, matrix, transform, surface

I've got a matrix in MATLAB with three columns, giving me x, y and z  values:

```
+----+-----+----+
| 65 | 300 | 10 |
| 65 | 500 |  5 |
| 70 | 300 |  9 |
| 70 | 500 |  4 |
| 75 | 300 |  8 |
| 75 | 500 |  3 |
+----+-----+----+
```

The x and y data can be made to always form a grid if necessary, but it would be advantageous if they did not have to.

I'd like to create a 3D surface with this data.

I believe that means I need to transform the data such that I have Z(x,y), like:

```
+-----+----+----+----+
|     | 65 | 70 | 75 |
+-----+----+----+----+
| 300 | 10 |  9 |  8 |
| 500 |  5 |  4 |  3 |
+-----+----+----+----+
```

At which point I think I can just call surface(Z).

What's the best way to make that happen in MATLAB?

Comment: Do the `x` and `y` always from a grid, as in your example?

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the response! Yes they do.

Comment: Please edit that information into the question to get it reopened

Comment: Meanwhile, try `M = [65 300 10; 65 500 5; 70 300 9; 70 500 4; 75 300 8; 75 500 3]; M = sortrows(M); ii = unique(M(:,1)); jj = unique(M(:,2)); surf(ii,jj,reshape(M(:,3), numel(jj), numel(ii)))`

Comment: @luisMendo -- Thanks!  After playing around with it a bit, I've realized that while my data can be made to form a grid, that may not be ideal in some cases (where I don't need that much data).  Is there a way to do it if my dataset is "rectangular"?

I've updated my question.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the data form a grid, as in your example, the code in my previous example should work

Comment: Does [How can I plot a function with two variables in Octave or Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061) answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [delaunay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html#f81-998526) triangulation and plot it using [`trisurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html) (triangular surface plot) as follows.

```
T = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(T,x,y,z);
```

Comment: Thanks S Bawazeer!  That works!  It produces what appears to be a black surface with the dataset I'm using (larger than in the example I provided), though when you expand the graph and look closely, it's thousands of triangles.  I'll try playing with the line settings to get it back to a gradient.

Comment: Alternate without triangularization:  [How can I plot a function with two variables in Octave or Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061)